# Int cannot represent non-integer value: Int

Tags: reactjs, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo, apollo-server

I have this Apollo query:

```
  currentUser: async (root, args) => {
    const currentUser = await prisma.user.findUnique({
      where: {id: Number(args.id)},
    });
    console.log(currentUser);
    return currentUser;
  },
```

and in the playground I can call it:

```
query Query {
  currentUser(id: 1) {
    id
  }
}
```

In the Apollo server log it shows:"

```
{
  id: 1,
  email: 'peter@**.nl',
  name: 'Peter **',
  password: '$2b$04$Dqo4LN3S5ZOnk1T1MyatOuijbvHpl281oDChHdEu1ZfEOyk7mjLqu'
}
```

```
  type Query {
    currentUser (id: Int!): User
  }
```

But when I try to call the query from my React client I get an error:

```
const ReturnCurrentUser = gql`
  query Query {
    currentUser(id: Int) {
      id
    }
  }
`;

const {loading, error, data} = useQuery(ReturnCurrentUser, {variables: {id: 1}});
```

The error:

> Int cannot represent non-integer value: Int

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my resolver was wrong:

```
const ReturnCurrentUser = gql`
  query currentUser($id: Int!) {
    currentUser(id: $id) {
      id
    }
  }
`;
```

fixed the issue.